# Making Model Associations to make Queries easier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, model

I've came up with a Database Schema, but I feel it's more influenced by my old SQL habits than a Rails ORM.  Here is the schema I developed.  [image]

Currently, I have made models for all the tables in the image above, however, after researching associations, I believe that I can just use Rails Associations to produce some of the many-to-many relational tables.

In my PlayerStats#index I find myself doing things like `<%= Year.find(TeamYear.find(TeamUser.find(player_stat.team_user_id).team_year_id).year_id).year %>` which I know is not good.  So, I'm looking for guidance on how to build model associations based on the normalized schema above.  Here is my guess:

User.rb
  has_many :team_users

Team.rb
  belongs_to :team_year

Year.rb
  belongs_to :team_year

Team_Year.rb
  has_many :teams
  has_many :years

Team_User.rb
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team_year
  has_one :role

Game.rb
  has_many :team_years

Player_stats.rb
  belongs_to :team_user
  belongs_to :game

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not.  Furthermore, I'm not sure how to take advantage of declaring these associations.  I'd definitely like to make the Team.name (given Player_Stat.game_id) a lot easier than `Team.find(TeamYear.find(Game.find(player_stat.game_id).away_team_year_id).team_id).name`.

Am I trying too hard to have a normalized DB?  Should I be thinking about this problem differently?  I appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Do you read this guide? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Look on has_many through association.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB Design is fine...

Consider for e.g. the common one to many relationships:

User model, and a Subject model having userid with it..

Now in sql terms you would put a user id in Subject. Subject[ id, userid, marks]

so in subject model you will define `userid belongs_to User`..

Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html this in detail atleast once..and maybe try it a little in rails console with one two tables... and you will be good to go...

Also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html has nice and clear explanation with example look from heading 'Cardinality and associations' in it...

Answer (score 0):

The DB Design seems OK, except the Game-TeamYear relation, witch is unclear, but the direction of the query is not just what is easier to do.

Try starting the building not from the top, but from the base, in your case your query

```
<%= Year.find(TeamYear.find(TeamUser.find(player_stat.team_user_id).team_year_id).year_id).year %>
```

transforms into

```
<%= player_stat.team_user.team_year.year %>
```

and the query

```
Team.find(TeamYear.find(Game.find(player_stat.game_id).away_team_year_id).team_id).name
```

transforms into

```
TeamYear.find(player_stat.game.away_team_year_id).team.name
```

So you just go from inside query to the outside query, hope you got the idea.